# PHPMailer displays mail on top of page

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to send emails. On one of my pages the mail script runs before the page is displayed. The mail is sent and it is also displayed on the screen above the content of the page. Why?

```
<?php
/* many things */
        $mail             = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                 
        $mail-> Host      = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->Port       = 465;                   

        $mail->Username   = "donotreply@example.com";  
        $mail->Password   = "password";            
        $mail->SetFrom('donotreply@example.com', 'Example Support');
        $mail->AddAddress($email);

        $mail->Subject    = $subject;
        $mail->Body       = $message;           

        $mail->CharSet     = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->Encoding    = '8bit';
        $mail->ContentType = 'text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n';
        //$mail->WordWrap = 70;

        $mail->Send();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<!--many things-->
</html>
```

Using the mail() function of php I never had this problem:

```
mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: Maybe try commenting out `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;`?

Comment: Use `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // code }` then name your submit button to `name="submit"` if that's what I think is going on. I may be misinterpreting your question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That's definitly not the question and has nothing to do with it. BTW you missed a '

Comment: @wumm Hence my edited comment. I evidently misunderstood. And yeah, no biggie on the missed `'` ;-) am sure someone would've figured that one out. (edited) that's what the "comments" box is for ;-)

Comment: @andrewsi add it as a solution. thanks.